# Android->Приложение->Потоки->AsyncStack Как сделать заставку для приложения,которая исчезнет через n секунд

Tags: android, многопоточность, android-asynctask

Подскажите,пожалуйста,как реализовать **Asyntask** для следующей задачи,у меня есть *MainActivity*, в котором находится *ListView*, содержащий *1000* элементов. Мне нужно,чтобы перед *MainActivity* запускалось другое *Activity*, содержащее только картинку, проходило 2 секунды, *Activity* исчезает и появляется *MainActivity*.

Answer (score 3):

Это называется `Splash Screen`

Вот пример реализации:

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 2000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }
}
```

Смысл кода я думаю пояснять нет необходимости.

Comment: Спасибо большое!Все ясно и понятно!